# How to separate the .java and .class file in Vs Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

**When we compile a java code the .class file is created in the same place where the source code is .  Is there a way like when we compile a java code the .class file file will be formed in a different folder**

I tried creating projects and then writing the code but it didn't work

---

***Edit: The problem is solved. I created a java project in VS Code then the source code is in src folder and the .class file is in bin folder. Thank You everyone....***

---

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.
When you compile your java file with

```
javac file.java
```

This  default stores *.class* of that file in same folder.

To store *.class* in different folder use -d paramter with javac as:

```
javac file.java -d "Path"
```

For ex:

```
javac file.java -d "D:/Classes"
```

Then while running the files you have to set classpath so that JVM will search class files in that folder:

```
java -classpath "D:/Classes" file
```

FYI:
If your file name is say **Test.java** and when you run javac, **Test.class** gets created at the path mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path where your .class is created following the next steps:

- File -> Preferences ->Settings
- Write java.output on the search bar and it should show you "Java > Project : Output Path.
- Click on edit in setting.json and write the new path where you want your .class to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you compile manually with command line javac ?
If so you can make a bash script (if you are on linux) that move all class file to another directory after compilation.

Something like:

```
mv *.class destination/
```

I think you have similar command on windows.

In vscode you can can then configure your launch.json to execute that command as well as the compilation one.

Comment: No i didn't compiled manually
I just used the extensions

Comment: Have you been able to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a project folder. eg. Test-Project
2. Create src file in Test-Project. (You can name in what ever you want.)
3. Create .vscode/settings.json in Test-project
4. Write this in settings.json

   - `{ "java.project.outputPath": "bin" }`

**Note**: Remember to use Run java instead of Run Code when compiling and running.
This will automatically create bin folder and put the .class files inside it for every new class.

---

I did a lot of digging on the internet and finally came up with this solution:)
Thank you.